# Сжатие html посредством кода, вызывает ли данный код какую-то нагрузку и есть от него польза?

Tags: php, dle

[Нашёл на просторах интернета код](https://byroot.ru/99-minifikaciya-html-koda-stranicy-v-dle.html) минификации html. Хотелось бы спросить у знающих, есть ли смысл от такого кода? Интересует также возможная нагрузка от использования этого кода. Также хотелось бы узнать какой из трёх вариантов лучше ?

В index.php который в корне сайта выше строчки

```
@ob_start ();
```

вставить код (вариант 1)

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
$search = array('/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s', '/<!--(.*?)-->/', '/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s');
$replace = array('>', '<', '\\1', '', '>', '<', '\\1');
$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

ИЛИ вариант 2

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
$search = array('/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s', '/<!--(.*?)-->/', '/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s');
$replace = array('>', '<', '\\1', '<!--\\1-->', '>', '<', '\\1');
$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

ИЛИ вариант 3

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
$search = array(

'/\>[^\S ]+/s', // Прокладка пробелы после тегов, кроме космоса
'/[^\S ]+\</s', // Прокладка пробелы перед тегами, за исключением космоса
'/\s{5,}/' // если виджеты работать не будут поставить цыфру 4/3/5

);

$replace = array(
'>',
'<',
'\\1'
);
$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

Далее в /engine/modules/main.php найти

```
echo $tpl->result['main'];
```

заменить на

```
ob_start("sanitize_output");
echo $tpl->result['main'];
ob_end_flush();
```

[Источник тут](https://byroot.ru/99-minifikaciya-html-koda-stranicy-v-dle.html)

Comment: Если у вас чистый и красивый/правильный код то подобным заниматься смысла нет.

Comment: красивый, но cms ОТВРАТИТЕЛЬНО его вставляет. есть неуместная табуляция. глаза мозолит. хотелось бы ответ по существу)

Comment: По существу, я бы перестал пользоваться cms) Хотите менять - меняйте. Я с этим не сталкивался, поэтому не знаю что там как меняет, просто учитывайте что код должен быть таким, чтоб было не стыдно показать.

Comment: согласен, но cms годная. такая проблема из-за тегов,их в шаблоне нужно иначе записывать, или прям там сжать html и тогда норм будет... тогда придётся приводить код в первоначальный вид и это не оч удобно, поэтому, хочу такую минификацию кода на стороне бэка.

Comment: Годная cms, но портит код, чудеса... Я бы такую "годную" cms не использовал, как и любую другую, имхо

Comment: если ты любую другую не использовал бы, то смысла в этом диалоге 0, понял. смотри в чём проблема https://imgbb.su/image/vHBWOy вот, но это нет прямого влияния на код. и опять же, это можно решить минификацией кода в файлах шаблона.

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендуется самостоятельно кодировать методы сжатия, вместо этого используйте встроенное сжатие. Вот некоторые из них, которые вам могут понадобиться:

Сжатие строк Gzip: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php
Буферизация вывода с помощью обработчика gzip: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Кроме того, в предоставленных вами кодах:

Вариант 1 - это в основном удаление разрывов строк и комментариев в вашем коде.
Вариант 2 удаляет только разрывы строк.
Вариант 3 удаляет только разрывы строк.

Вариант 1 удаляет большинство вещей, так что они будут в основном сведены к минимуму.

Для вариантов 1 и 2 я не вижу никакого смысла добавлять '/ > [^ \S ] + / s', '/ [^ \S ] + \ < / s', '/ (\s) + / s', они просто удваивают вещи.

Нет необходимости сворачивать html-код, это снижает его удобочитаемость (или, может быть, это ваша цель) и на самом деле не снижает скорость загрузки небольших файлов (вам нужно несколько МБ, чтобы увидеть значительные результаты), но может даже увеличить ее, потому что необходимо выполнять проверки регулярных выражений.

**Ответ на мой вопрос написал** [Henryc17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14595300/henryc17) (stackoverflow.com) за что ему **большое спасибо!**